# SQL to Determine Tee Order in Golf Application

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I am working on a golf application that includes a scorecard system. I am storing each score for each player in the database and I need to come up with a query to determine tee order. So for example if the players have played 3 holes and the scores look like this...

```
Player    1  2  3
--------- -  -  -
Player 1: 3, 4, 3
Player 2: 2, 3, 3
Player 3: 2, 4, 3
```

... Then the order needs to look like this...

```
1.) Player 2
2.) Player 3
3.) Player 1
```

... So the players will be ordered by their scores compared to their opponents scores. Does that make sense? Is this even possible with a query, or should I write a function to parse a 2d array in code? I am using Java in that case.

My table structure looks like this:

- Players (player id, and player name)
- Rounds (round id, course id)
- Scores (round id, player id, hole number, and score)

Comment: Is the sorting done by total score or by the last hole, then the one previous, etc?

Comment: Sorting would be the lowest previous score. So for Player 2, you can see that they beat the other two players on hole 2 so Player 2 would be first. Then to keep going back (starting at hole 2 and not counting Player 2), Player 3 beat Player 1 on hole 1 and that makes Player 3 ordered second, resulting in Player 1 ordered last. Does that clear things up? Confusing I know haha

Comment: I'd suggest you do it in java

Comment: How are you pivoting the data to get the results in the first set?

Comment: @Keyser I'm thinking that is what I will do, but I wanted to see if it is possible with a query first...

Comment: @WillP. Sorry, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Basically how are you turning the hole scores from rows in the "Scores" table into columns in the first result set you're showing

Comment: @WillP. Gotcha, the data shown above is not the straight results from a query, I just tried to show the data in a clear way that is relevant to how a scorecard would look. The score data would be selected for each player and then displayed separately.

Comment: If you were doing some kind of dynamic pivot it might not be too difficult, but otherwise as Keyser says it's probably easier to figure out the order in the code.

Comment: It looks like sum of scores for the players are: Player1=10, Player2=8,Player3=9. Is it valid to sort by sum() to get ranks?

Comment: Em why not just do top (3) and order by the sum of the scores ASC, that should tell you the top scores for each round right?

Comment: sum won't work.  In golf, the winner of the previous hole is first on the next.  If multiple players got the same score on the previous hole, then you go to the hole before that for those players, continuing back until you find a clear winner.

Comment: @vyegorov I'm afraid not. Say a player had done terribly all round and had a really high score, but their last hole they shot really well and beat their opponents. That would put them first in the tee order. Does that make sense?

Comment: Who goes first on a straight tie across the board?

Comment: @MarcusAdams This is a great question, in golf it would be the order of the first hole. But because I am not currently storing that information it wont work. See Gordon Linoff's answer below for the solution to this problem, as well as my overall problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a solution that uses windows functions row_number() and an additional column in the database for the ordering at each level (or a recursive CTE in SQL Server).  However, SQLite does not support this.

Here is my recommendation on implementing the solution without doing a lot of querying backwards:

(1) Assign the tee order for the first tee.

(2) For each next tee, look at the previous score and the previous tee order:

(3) Assign the new tee order by looping through the previous scores by ordering by highest score DESC and previous tee order ASC.

Because you only have a few players per round, it is reasonable to do this in the app layer.  However, if you had a database that supported window function, then you could more easily do a database only solution.

I can't resist.  Here some code that will do this with a table to store the orders.  You need to loop through, once per hole:

```
create table ThisOrder (
    ThisOrderId int primary key autoincrement,
    RoundId int,
    Hole int,
    PlayerId int
)
```

Initialize it with each player in some order.

Then, insert new rows into the table for each hole:

```
insert into ThisOrder(RoundId, HoleId, PlayerId)
    select s.RoundId, s.Hole+1, s.PlayerId
    from Scores s join
         ThisOrder to
         on s.PlayerId = to.PlayerId and
            s.RoundId = to.RoundId and
            s.Hole = to.Hole
    order by s.Score DESC, to.Order ASC
```

You'll need to call this once for each hole, minus one.

Then get your ordering as:

```
 select *
 from ThisOrder
 where roundid = <roundid> and hole = <thehole>
 order by ThisOrderId
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of this, I like this solution because I could simply just query the tee order column at any time. It is lightweight because it is only looking back at the previous hole scores and not processing every score for every player each time I would like to know the tee order. Thank you, I will definitely consider this.

Comment: Haha thanks for the edits, you have definitely won me over with this one. I like this approach much more than my original thoughts. Great solution, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you'd need to sum up the scores for each hole previous to the current hole for each player, then sort the list of player IDs by the summed scores.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS score, player_id FROM Scores WHERE round_id=$current_round AND hole_number<$current_hole GROUP BY player_id ORDER BY score;
```

This results in a results table of two columns (player_id and score) with as many rows as there are players, putting the player with the highest score first.

Comment: Something like this won't work because I need to do the ordering based on the previous lowest score compared to opponents scores, not by total score unfortunately. This method will work if I would like to determine who is winning.

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the highest hole where the player had the lowest score and orders by that:

```
SELECT * FROM Players p
ORDER BY
  (SELECT MAX(s1.hole_number) FROM Scores s1
   LEFT JOIN Scores s2
     ON s2.round_id = s1.round_id AND
        s1.hole_number = s2.hole_number AND
        s2.score < s1.score
   WHERE s1.player_id = p.player_id AND
     s1.round_id = 1 AND s2.round_id IS NULL) DESC
```

Comment: I understand where you are going with this, but it doesn't quite get it. Especially if there has only been one hole played and there were ties on that hole, it won't have any idea how to determine the correct order (my fault with the table structure). If every player had a different score on every hole then this would work.

Comment: @Alex_Hyzer_Kenoyer, I agree. Add another ORDER BY expression with the original order like `ORDER BY (...) DESC, player_order ASC`.